# Displaying Specific record on pdf from a custom object using SOQL Query in Apex class

Tags: apex, soql, class, custom, object

Please i'm new to visualforce and  Apex classes. I need help displaying a specific record from a custom object on pdf format using the record id or a unique identifier as parameters. right now i can only display one record and its a wrong record not related to the current page for the generated purchase order pdf See my code below and help me make corrections.

```
 public class contractorController {
 public Contractor_LPO__c purchaseList {get;set;} 
public string recordId {get;set;}

public contractorController () 
{ 
recordId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
purchaseList =new Contractor_LPO__c(); purchaseList = [select Id, Contractor_Quote__r.Contractor_Account__c, Contractor_Quote__r.id , Contractor_Quote__r.Amount_in_Words__c, Contractor_LPO__c.Name, Amount_in_Words__c, Contractor_Quote_Approved_Amount__c, Contractor_Quote_Status__c, Contractor_RFQ_Number__c, LPO_Date__c, Payment_Terms_and_Condition__c, Quantity__c, Quote_Description__c , Contractor_Quote__c,Status__c, Tax_Inclusive_Amount__c,Value_Added_Tax__c , VAT_Inclusive__c, Contractor_Account__c from Contractor_LPO__c limit 1]; 
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

**APEX Controller:**

```
//If Extension
public class customExtension {

public customObject custRec{get;set;}
public String custRec{get;set;}

public customExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    String recID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    //Can retrive record details from SOQL
    //Can do any complicated caluclations and assign eg. to custRec
}
}
```

-

```
//If custom controller
public class customController {

public customObject custRec{get;set;}
public String custRec{get;set;}

public customController () {
    String recID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    //Can retrive record details from SOQL
    //Can do any complicated caluclations and assign eg. to custRec
}
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**   Name : DemoPDF

```
<!-- with standard controller -->
 <apex:page standardController="CustomObject" extensions="customExtension" renderAs="pdf">
Here you can display any field related to current custom object record using 
relatedTo directly
<apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Field1__c}" />
Or you can access value from extension
<apex:outputLabel value="{!custRec}" />
</apex:page>
```

-

```
<!-- with custom controller -->
<apex:page  controller="customController" renderAs="pdf" >
Here you can display any field related to cuurent custom object record using 
relatedTO
<apex:outputLabel value="{!custRec}" />
</apex:page>
```

You can access\test same pdf page by accessing :
`{organization base url}/apex/DemoPDF?id={record ID}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya! Your answer is Fantastic.  What is the best SOQL Filter Clause to use with custRec from your example? e.g can I use Where, or Like. E.g purchaseList =new Contractor_LPO__c(); purchaseList = [select Id, Contractor_Quote__r.Contractor_Account__c, , Quote_Description__c , Contractor_Quote__c,Status__c, Tax_Inclusive_Amount__c,Value_Added_Tax__c , VAT_Inclusive__c, Contractor_Account__c from Contractor_LPO__c Where Id=: custRec ];  Is this correct? if its not can you type best way to filter the SOQL Query for best results? thankyou Ajinkya